# nw.js extracting zip/rar file

Tags: node-webkit, rar

I'm making a game downloader/launcher using node webkit. I'm able to download a rar file but now I can't find anywhere online how to "unzip" the rar file to a certain directory. Anyone know how I can do this with nw.js?